# how to recalculate something ~once per second?

Tags: c#

I need to do some pretty fast recalculation ~every second.
What is the best way to do that? Is using dedicated thread and `Thread.Sleep` is ok?

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                RecalculateState();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: What is the kind of application? Winform? Wpf? Asp.Net ? Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would work - but another alternative would be to use a timer, e.g. [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) or [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

You should think about:

- What do you want to happen if it takes more than a second to recalculatte state?
- Is your `RecalculateState` method entirely safe to be called from arbitrary threads?

Comment: `RecalculateState` is called only from one point and is private. it updates this field `public StrategyState State { get; private set; }`. `State` is changed rarely (several times per day), but read ofthen (several hundread millions times per day) so I have decided to recalculate it just once per second so callers can just get "cached" copy and not to spent extra time.

Comment: it is not critical if `RecalculateState` takes too much time (several seconds for example). In real life on every call it spents ~the same time to recalculate (~ several milliseconds)

Comment: @javapowered: Updating a single field in an unprotected way is a bad idea. You'll need to force memory barriers so that reads are guaranteed to fetch the latest value.

Comment: so what is the suggest way to recalculate single field once per second? Thread or Timer? need to use `Volatile.Write` `Volatile.Read` to update value?

Comment: @javapowered: A timer is more self-descriptive, IMO. `Volatile.*` is fine if it's a reference type - it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: it's an `enum`, how to deal with that?

Comment: @javapowered: Either back the property with an `int` or `long` field, and perform volatile reads/writes that way, or use locking.

Comment: but how can I convert enum to int/long and vise versa?

Comment: should I do something like that `YourEnum foo = Enum.ToObject(typeof(YourEnum) , yourInt);`?

Comment: @javapowered: No - you can simply cast from an enum value to its underlying type, and vice versa: `YourEnum foo = (YourEnum) intValue;` assuming the underlying type of `YourEnum` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) with 1 second [interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx).

It already runs in a new *thread* .

Pay attention on fact, that *if* `RecalculateState` runs longer than expected interval (for 1000 of reasons) you have to deal with calls overlapping, so you have to manage that case in some way.

One of possible solutions, is to run a new code only after execution of the method finished, and measure difference between execution time and interval. But this is not so easy task to do. Fortunatelly  someone already thought about that problem.

Can have a look on [Reactive Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/08/15/reactive-extensions-v2-0-has-arrived.aspx) that in latest build payed special attention on time dependent execution.

Comment: `RecalculateState` never takes more than 1 second and I do not need "precise" delay, just average. so just `Timer` should work but probably I should use `Volatile.Write` insider timer and users should use `Volatile.Read` to read recalculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a timer and make a ontimed event?
Something like this ?

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp()
       .Subscribe(MyOnTimedEventMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a timer for this.

member:

```
private readonly Timer _timer;
```

instantiate the timer in the constructor for instance:

```
_timer= new Timer(OnTimerEllapsed, null, 0, 1000);
```

callback:

```
private void OnTimerEllapsed(object sender)
{
    RecalculateState();
}
```

Comment: because you can instantly change the interval or pause the timer for a while. Additionally there is a difference with the interval. With the timer the Recalculate gets called every second. Without the timer the calls a separated by a 1 second pause.

Comment: i don't care how exact pause is. also i don't need to change an interval or pause.